# html word generation - setting a footer image

Tags: html, css, ms-word

found this code that works absolutely well. But, I'm not able to figure out how to add an image to the footer. Any help would be great!

[HTML generated Microsoft Word document with header, footer and watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340216/html-generated-microsoft-word-document-with-header-footer-and-watermark)

Comment: did you try adding background or something to the f1 id ? (footer in that example)

Comment: yup.. and it didnt work.. in any case I need the image to be on the bottom right of every page