# Office HTML Word document line numbers

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, ms-office

I'm converting HTML into a Word document a la the approved comment here [HTML generated Microsoft Word document with header, footer and watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340216/html-generated-microsoft-word-document-with-header-footer-and-watermark)

I am wondering if there is a Word directive or the like to include line numbers in the document. If not, any pointers on how including line numbers can be accomplished?

Comment: If I'm following the Answer in your link correctly, this is generating a Word document using the (undocumented) round-trip HTML file format? Word does support line numbers: In any Word document in the Word application go to Page Layout, click the dialog launcher in the Page Setup group, go to the Layout tab and click "Line Numbers". Activate the kind of line numbers you want. Save the document to the HTML file format and inspect the HTML in order to see how Word wants you to write it... If that helps, I'll copy this to an "Answer" for others with the same question.

Comment: That worked! @CindyMeister