# MS Word .doc file save as type should be Word 97-2003 not Web Page

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I used php to create a Word file with the extension **.doc** using HTML content.
When I open the document it opens fine but when I try to Save As in dialog box it shows "Web Page" as the "Save as" type.

I used code like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13340217, 
https://daveismyname.blog/create-a-doc-file-with-php-on-the-fly

But I need it to default to the Word Document type of **Word 97-2003 Document**
because the user can't observe this format while saving.

I've attached an image of this issue:

**Save-as-type-issue-IMAGE**

[image]

(Note: That code needs some changes in php headers and html head tag elements.)

Can anyone provide a suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: If you really want a Word document that MS Word will teat as a word document, then you need to create a word document, not a block of html masquerading as a word document because it has a .doc extension.... MS Word doesn't know that your document should be saved as a word document because it isn't really a word document, it's html markup, so it treats it as such

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux)

Answer (score -1):

Look at "tools", at "save as" window, and save as specified format.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i need changes on code side not in ms office.

Comment: This should save as default, I believe is not a code matter, give it a try.

Comment: @ecp - The file being read is html markup, so that's what MS Word offers as the default format for saving, but poster wants that MS Word default  changing to Word 97-2003, which can only happen if the file  being read is a real word document