# unwanted squares in MS Word doc generated from HTML

Tags: html, ms-word

I'm creating a MS Word document from HTML using the code from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340216/html-generated-microsoft-word-document-with-header-footer-and-watermark). After some adaptions it's working fine for me, except now I'm getting squares at each end of the header and footer [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhuw4.png). Those squares cannot be manually removed and I don't see what is creating them.

To reproduce, just create a *.doc file, open it with a text editor like notepad++ or VS Code and enter the following code. Open the file with MS Word afterwards.

I hope you guys can help me get rid of those squares!

```
<html xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
    xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml'
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        @page {
            mso-page-orientation: portrait;
            margin: 1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;
        }

        @page Section1 {
            mso-header-margin: 1cm;
            mso-footer-margin: 1cm;
            mso-header: h1;
            mso-footer: f1;
        }

        div.Section1 {
            page: Section1;
        }

        table.hdrftrtbl {
            margin: 0in 0in 0in 900in;
            width: 1px;
            height: 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        p.MsoHeadFoot,
        li.MsoHeadFoot,
        div.MsoHeadFoot,
        td.MsoHeadFoot {
            margin: 0;
            margin-bottom:1px;
            tab-stops: center 50% right 100%;
            font-size: 12.0pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <br/>
    TODO: Actual content goes here

    <div class='Section1'>
        <table class='hdrftrtbl' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
            <tr>
                <!-- HEADER-tags -->
                <td class='MsoHeadFoot'>
                    <div style='mso-element:header' id='h1'>
                        <span style='mso-tab-count:2'>
                            <img src='logo.jpg' width="140" height="60">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <!-- end HEADER-tags -->
                <!-- FOOTER-tags -->
                <td class='MsoHeadFoot'>
                    <div style='mso-element:footer' id='f1'>
                        <span style='mso-tab-count:0'>&copy; company name</span>
                        <span style='mso-tab-count:1'>TODO: beginning from page 2</span>
                        <span style='mso-tab-count:1'></span>
                        page
                        <span style='mso-field-code:PAGE'></span>
                        of
                        <span style='mso-field-code:NUMPAGES'></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <!-- end FOOTER-tags -->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I had to add another `<div>` block for each header and footer:

```
<div style='mso-element:header'>
  <p class='MsoHeader'>
    <span>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

and accordingly

```
<div style='mso-element:footer'>
  <p class='MsoFooter'>
    <span>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Apparently the `<o:p></o:p>` tags are responsible for those squares.